# determine the infinite limit. limit x tends to 3, x^0.5/(x-3)^5

Tags: calculus

determine the infinite limit. limit x tends to 3-, x^0.5/(x-3)^5

I don't know how to determine. using words or calculating? I can't figure it out directly.

Comment: You have to do it via calculations. Why would words even suffice for this problem is beyond me. Besides, the key to your problem is realizing what the nature of the numerator and the denominator are , when $x$ goes to $3$ from the left  Study them separately, and combine them, using appropriate statements.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator goes to square root of three and the denominator goes to zero minus, so the ratio goes to minus infinity.